# Running a DIANA TNO model from within Python or MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, cmd

I have a model in [DIANA TNO](http://tnodiana.com/), and I was wondering if perhaps exist a way to execute the software from Python (more information click [here](https://support.tnodiana.com/manuals/d95/GetStart/node136.html)) or MATLAB?

The final idea is to be able to create projects / create and run analysis / process the results from MATLAB and/or Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, and I hope this be helpful for whatever could be your purposes.

There are the steps:

1. Create a .bat with the next information (for creating the .bat, just open a Notepad file and after save it, just change the extension to .bat):

```js
rem === Diana Environment Setup ===
call "C:\Program Files\Diana 9.6\dialogin.bat"

diana q8axi
```

2. Create a .dat, where basically has the information of your model, [here](https://support.tnodiana.com/manuals/d93/GetStart/node38.html) is an example.
3. Create a .dcf, where is specified the detail of the analysis that you want to perform. [Here](https://support.tnodiana.com/manuals/d93/GetStart/node45.html) is and example.
4. In MATLAB, create an script with the next information:

```js
clc, clear all, close all
dos('NAME.bat')
```

Note: It's very important take into account that all the previous files (.bat .dat .dcf) got to have the same NAME.

5. Finally, just save and run the Matlab file in the same folder where are located the others files.

Now you are able run a parametric analysis between MATLAB and DIANA TNO.